# How to store array of components returned by map() function in this.state Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, tabs

This function returns Category component

```
 renderCategory = (category, index) => {
        return (
          <Category
            key={index}
            category={category}
          />
        );
      };
```

Here the array of components need to be added at Tab Content 1

```
 state = {
          initialData: [
            {
              label: "Tab 1",
              content: "Tab Content 1" // Here I need to store the array of Components //
            },
            {
              label: "Tab 2",
              content: "Tab Content 2"
            }
          ]
        };
```

map function returns array of components

```
render(){
   return(
        <div>
           // *I need to pass the below data at **Tab Content 1*** //
           {this.props.categories.map(this.renderCategory)}
        </div>
   )
}
```

Comment: [You generally don't want to store React elements in state](http://web.archive.org/web/20150419023006/http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/interactivity-and-dynamic-uis.html#what-shouldnt-go-in-state). What is your use case?

Comment: Can you please share Html of the tab component because you need to create 3 separate Html of the tab component and manage which tab selected?
Please refer to this doc for the material UI tab component for reactJs
https://material-ui.com/components/tabs/

Comment: @Tholle I need to add tabs in the page. separate the content in the page in to tab1 and tab 2.
I know libraries are available but need to do without them.